# Default GWT Checkbox to unchecked

Tags: java, gwt, checkbox

I have the following simple class which extends Checkbox and want to make it so that the Checkboxes default to unchecked upon creation. I tried calling setValue(false) in this class however the checkboxes are still defaulting to checked. Any help is appreciated

```
 public final class ServerTaskCheckBox extends CheckBox {

    private final ServerTask serverTask;

    public ServerTaskCheckBox(ServerTask serverTask) {
        super(serverTask.getCheckBoxLabel());
        this.serverTask = serverTask;
        setValue(false);
    }

    public ServerTask getServerTask() {
        return serverTask;
    }

}
```

Comment: setFormValue takes a string not boolean and doesn't seem to help either

Comment: Shouldn't they default to unchecked anyway? Are you sure that no code actually checks them after you create them? Or have you played with its css, maybe it just appears checked or something like that?

Comment: Override method setValue and set a breakpoint inside it to see who is checking it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value of a checkbox is `false` / unchecked. I assume that you have a `setValue(true)` somewhere else in your code.